# What is VREF pin?

Tags: arduino-uno, power, pins

Was searching for some help on connecting Flir camera w/ Lepton board to arduino and found this thread
[image]

*for power you can reroute the 3-5V to the VREF pin, then you have a nice clean solution.
You have to use a Ardunio with at least 16k or ram so you can buffer the image.*

Was that a typo and he meant AREF?  If so would the VIN from the camera be connected to the VIN on arduino otherwise?

Thread:
https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=266361.0

Answer (score 2):

VREF normally means Voltage REFerence.  Such pins are usually associated with ADCs (Analog to Digital Converters).  For example a 3.3 volt microprocessor may have a VREF pin fed by 2 volts.  The 10 bit ADC inside the microprocessor sees this as the upper limit.  That is, a 2 volt input to the ADC will produce the maximum value or 2^10 or 1024.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, he meant AREF.  What he is showing there is the board plugged direct into the Arduino's header, but the VIN of the Lepton board connects to AREF not a voltage pin. By connecting your supply voltage (5V) direct to that AREF pin you are then able to provide power to the Lepton board, and it has no noticeable effect on the Arduino since connecting 5V to AREF is a perfectly valid thing to do (though pretty pointless).

AREF and VREF are both pretty much interchangeable. Analog REFerence, and Voltage REFerence. It could be said that one is the Analog voltage REFerence, and the other is the Voltage REFerence for analog. Some chips call it AREF and some VREF. Some even provide VREF+ and VREF- or AREF+ and AREF- depending on the complexity of the ADC in the chip.