# What is the REF pin for -- pin 9 on ATSAMD21G18-QFN48?

Tags: samd21g

32-bit ARM-Based microcontroller SAM D21E / SAM D21G /SAM D21J

I have a Seeeduino XIAO [PDF to schematic](https://files.seeedstudio.com/wiki/Seeeduino-XIAO/res/Seeeduino-XIAO-v1.0-SCH-191112.pdf) which uses a [ATSAMD21G18-QFN48](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/40001884a.pdf) chip. Pin D1 on the Seeeduino is pin 9 on the chip; which is labeled as `PA4/EIC/REF/AIN4/SCOM0PAD0/TC0`.

[image: screenshot with highlighted pin in question]

What would the `REF` pin be used for; and how would the pin be addressed in the code?

Based on [this post](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/24529/71398) is sound like it is ADC related.

There is no indication about this on the https://wiki.seeedstudio.com/Seeeduino-XIAO/ website. Only this image:
[image: Seeeduino XIAO pin layout]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PA04 pin can be a normal GPIO or a voltage reference pin (similar to VDDANA). So, the ADC input will be compared to this VREF pin in the application if needed. If you have configured it as GPIO, then it will behave as a normal IO pin. It depends on how you configure it.
[image]
[image]
[image]